# How can i export the same logs from the console using this power shell function?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

I have this function running to get Bandwidth utilization over a period of time when i try to Out-File it shows Shows one line.

```
 # Measure the Network interface IO over a period of half a minute (0.5)



Function Net-utilization {

$startTime = get-date
$endTime = $startTime.addMinutes(0.5)
$timeSpan = new-timespan $startTime $endTime

$count = 0
$totalBandwidth = 0

while ($timeSpan -gt 0) {
   # Get an object for the network interfaces, excluding any that are currently disabled.
   $colInterfaces = Get-CimInstance -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface |select BytesTotalPersec, CurrentBandwidth,PacketsPersec|where {$_.PacketsPersec -gt 0}

   foreach ($interface in $colInterfaces) {
      $bitsPerSec = $interface.BytesTotalPersec * 8
      $totalBits = $interface.CurrentBandwidth

      # Exclude Nulls (any WMI failures)
      if ($totalBits -gt 0) {
         $result = (( $bitsPerSec / $totalBits) * 100)
         Write-Host "Bandwidth utilized:`t $result %"
         $totalBandwidth = $totalBandwidth + $result
         $count++
      }
   }
   Start-Sleep -milliseconds 100

   # recalculate the remaining time
   $timeSpan = new-timespan $(Get-Date) $endTime
}

"Measurements:`t`t $count"

$averageBandwidth = $totalBandwidth / $count
$value = "{0:N2}" -f $averageBandwidth
Write-Host "Average Bandwidth utilized:`t $value %" 

}

$BandwidthUtil = Net-utilization
```

thanks

I tried this and it the console its showing:

```
Bandwidth utilized:  0.0002568 %
Bandwidth utilized:  0.0008968 %
Bandwidth utilized:  0.0001896 %
Bandwidth utilized:  0.000428 %
Bandwidth utilized:  0.0075608 %
Bandwidth utilized:  0.0001816 %
Bandwidth utilized:  0.00036 %
Bandwidth utilized:  0.0024248 %
Bandwidth utilized:  0.00018 %
Bandwidth utilized:  0.0096328 %
Average Bandwidth utilized:  0.02 %
```

but in the log file using out-file just shows:

Measurements:        67

Comment: That's because you're using `Write-Host` - it writes output, directly _to the host application_ (eg. the terminal in your console)

Comment: I think you would want to use Write-Output instead of Write-Host